Vuejs Page break problem in jsPdf when print receipt
I have 2 problems, my receipt is very long and when I export the pdf it has a page break, so I am keeping pdfHeight fixed. How can I make pdfHeight calculate the height automatically and not have a page break?


function exportConnectPdf() {
  const pdfWidth = 306;
  const pdfHeight = 500;
  const doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'p',
    unit: 'px',
    format: [pdfWidth, pdfHeight],
  });
  doc.html(fastConnectPrint.value, {
    callback: function (doc) {
      doc.save(`Order Receipt #${receipts.value.fast_connect_standalone == null ? receipts.value.data.id : receipts.value.fast_connect_standalone.id}.pdf`);
    },
    autoPaging: 'text',
    html2canvas: {
      scale: 1,
      useCORS: true,
      allowTaint: true,
      scrollY: -window.scrollY,
    }
  });
}
<div id="connect-print" style="display: none;">
  <div class="connect-print w-[306px]" ref="fastConnectPrint">
    ....Long content paragraph follows....
  </div>
</div>
<button @click="exportConnectPdf()">export pdf</button>



